# How do I randomly generate a valid E164-formatted phone number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phone-number, libphonenumber

For automated tests of my Rails app, I'd like to generate random phone numbers.

- Like all phone numbers in my system, these must be in E164 format.
- They must be valid phone numbers. (e.g. according to https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).
- Ideally non-US numbers are included.

How should I approach this?

Comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/global_phone

Comment: Hi @Cyzanfar, I use a similar library to *validate* phone numbers, but here I am concerned with *generating* them. Does GlobalPhone provide that functionality?

Comment: Have you looked at [ffaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker)?

Answer (score 2):

Found this question, didn't find an answer ([comic reference](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png)).

Indeed Faker gives out random numbers that are sometimes invalid. Checked what other libs in different languages do (eg. [python](https://github.com/crowdcomms/faker-e164)) and one solution adopted is to brute force Faker with Phony (here I also use PhonyRails because I'm using PhohyRails default locale for country codes)

```
def test_phone_number(locale=nil)

    # Magic to get your own app locale

    Faker::Config.locale = locale

    if [:fi, :de, ...].include?(locale)
        # faker locales that allow cell_phone call
        Faker::PhoneNumber.cell_phone
    else
        Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number
    end
end

def valid_phone_number!
     number = test_phone_number
     attempts = 0

     while !Phony.plausible?(PhonyRails.normalize_number(number))
         number = test_phone_number
         attempts += 1
         if attempts > 100
             raise "Cannot generate valid phone number" 
         end
     end
     number
end
```

Answer (score 1):

why not include the Faker Gem 
https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/doc/phone_number.md

Comment: Faker doesn't check to ensure that the phone numbers it generates are valid -- it just fills them with random digits.